# How to compare ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `t1` and table `t2`.Were as in table `t1` primary constraints will be in disabled status. Primary constraint is on column `C1,C2` And table `t2`do not have any constraint.

When I try to enable Primary constraint `PK_test` in table `t1` if there is any exception(records violates constraint) will be saved in table `t2`.Table `t1` will have columns `c1,c2`as shown below.

```
C1   C2 ROWID
1     2 ABCD
1     2 ABCE
1     2 ABCF
7     8 ABCI
```

And table `t2` will have column `ROWID` with data

```
ROWID
ABCD
ABCE
ABCF
```

since only these rows violating `PK`

So I wanted to keep only the `min(ROWID)` in table `t2` for the columns `C1,C2`.
So I have written a query

```
delete * 
from t2 
where ROWID not in(select min(ROWID) 
                     from t1 
                    where ROWID in (select ROWID 
                                      from t2) 
                     group by C1,C2);
```

But the above query is writing NULL also `select min(rowed)..`  query returning `1 ROWS(ABCD)` correctly.

Please help to find what exactly is wrong here.

Comment: Is `ROWID` a actually a column in your table or are you referring to the [ROWID Pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: I am referring to the ROWID pseudo column

Comment: OK, and table `t2` has an actual column `ROWID`? I suggest you change the name of `t2.rowid`, I'm not sure if that might interfere with Oracle's internal ROWID.

Comment: even after changing t2.rowid same result

Comment: Don't use `ROWID` as a column name. It's an internal Oracle function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm trying to delete t2.ROWID that are greater than min(ROWID) of any t1 that has the same C1 and C2

```
delete t2 
where t2."ROWID" > (select min(a."ROWID") 
                      from t1 join t1 a on t1.c1 = a.c1 and t1.c2 = a.c2
                     where t1."ROWID" = t2."ROWID");
```

Comment: what if inner query `select min(a.rowed)..` returns more than 1 row?

Comment: @teepu it cannot return more than one, anyway since I'm not exactly sure of your case, please try it on a test/dev system.

Comment: @teepu ok, I think it's because ROWID is a reserved word. Use double-quotes (or better don't use reserved words)

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint :) actually in table t2 I have a column named row_num. But in my queries I was reffering it as ROWNUM :(.after correcting it is working

Answer (score 1):

I would write this simply as:

```
delete t2
    where t2."RowId" not in (select min(t1."RowId")
                             from t1
                             group by c1, c2
                            );
```